# New values are added to the head of the linked list in separate chaining

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

We know in hashing, when a key collide, the new value should be inserted at the head of the linked list. What is the reason for that?.

Comment: Is this about a `hashtable`, rather than a `hash`?

Comment: @Renat Yes. Hash table. Why we cannot insert new value at the end of the linked list?. Is there any reason?.

Comment: You can add it anywhere in the list.

Comment: You don't have to put it at the head of the list, but the head is the easiest and fastest location to perform an insertion.  If you want to put it someplace else then you have to traverse the list to get to that other location.  Depending on how the hashtable will be used it might be worthwhile to do that extra work.  For example, keeping the list in a sorted order might improve search times for unmatched keys if the list becomes long.  But it's better to keep the lists short if you can, by using more buckets or a different hash, and then ordering is unimportant.